# System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException Message: Unable to find assembly 'Lucene.Net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, serialization

Run code below on Application_Start event in asp.net website：

```
public void CheckRebuildTasks()
{
try
{
    var ts = _rebuildRepository.Source.unCompleteRoots();

    if (ts.Any())
    {
        var task = new Task(() =>
        {
            int s = 30;
            string nameList = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                ts.ToList().ForEach(
                    t =>
                    nameList +=
                    string.Format("{0}[{1}]", t.AppName, t.AppContentName));
                _log.Info(string.Format("Sleep {0}s to continue {1}", s, nameList));
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30*1000);
                ts.ToList().ForEach(t =>
                                        {
                                            var appContent =
                                                _appContentRepository.GetBy(
                                                    t.AppName,
                                                    t.
                                                        AppContentName);
                                            this.ClearRebuild(appContent.Name,
                                                                appContent.
                                                                    ContentType);

                                            var si = new SmartIndexer(appContent,
                                                                        _zzkDocumentRepository,
                                                                        _rebuildRepository);
                                            si.Rebuild(t);
                                        });
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                _log.Error(exc);
            }
        });
        task.LogExceptions("CheckRebuildTasks");
        task.Start();
    }
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    _log.Error("CheckRebuildTasks", exc);
}
```

}

windows EventLog message：

> An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.
>   Application ID: DefaultDomain
>
> Process ID: 19232
>
> Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
>
> Message: Unable to find assembly 'Lucene.Net, Version=2.9.4.1,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=85089178b9ac3181'.
>
> StackTrace:    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo
>   assemblyInfo, String name)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String
>   objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA,
>   Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader
>   objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo,
>   SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary._*BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped
>   record)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.*_BinaryParser.Run()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler
>   handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    at
>   System.AppDomain.Deserialize(Byte[] blob)    at
>   System.AppDomain.UnmarshalObject(Byte[] blob)

PS: already reference Lucene.Net, and program runs well in local pc

Comment: As it runs on your local PC I'm guessing you mean it's broken on another machine. Does that machine have exactly the same version of the Lucene dll as yours?

Comment: Thanks for your response, exactly same version.this problem already solved,this error happend when an unhandled exception in a task.

Comment: I have this exact same problem. we have all of our proxies and DTOs in the same project, and every once and a while we get this exact same error message.